# bscTestnet hardhat deployment problem

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, testnets, web3-providers, binance-smart-chain

I've been racking my brain for quite a while now.

Before, I was able to deploy my code in bscTestnet with no problem, but recently, without changing any code it always stuck and it's not working. so my suspect was my 3rd party provider, then I checked and changed the provider to see if it's working (it's working). and after that, I also tried the same script for goerli testnet. the goerli testnet worked, no problem at all.

Can anyone help me? below is my **hardhat.config.js**, thank you!

```
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    bscTestnet: {
      url: process.env.BSC_TESTNET_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.DEPLOYER1, process.env.DEPLOYER2],
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 5000000000,
    },

    goerli: {
      url: process.env.GOERLI_TESTNET_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.DEPLOYER1, process.env.DEPLOYER2],
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 5000000000,
    }
  }
```

Comment: It happened with me couple of times! Try deleting node_modules and try again. If it doesn't work wait for awhile before trying once again.

Comment: thanky you sir, but I've already tried this one. I'll try this again from time to time. its sucks to deploy manually on remix lol